# Undefined references in GSL

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference, gsl

I'm trying to link gsl in a small c program.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_block_float.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_matrix_float.h"

int main(void)
{
  gsl_matrix_float* m = gsl_matrix_float_alloc(2, 2);
  gsl_matrix_float_fprintf(stdout, m, "%f");
}
```

I'm compiling with `gcc -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm program.c`. I've tried `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gsl) $(pkg-config --libs gsl) program.c` as well, along with `gsl-config`. In every case, gcc returns

```
/tmp/cc1wKgXm.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_float_alloc'
program.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_float_fprintf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`objdump --syms /usr/lib/libgsl.so | grep gsl_matrix_float` returns the proper symbols, as does grepping my headers. Everything is in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/include` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing the order of your linking. `gcc -lgslcblas -lm  -lgsl program.c`

Comment: @CholNhial: if anything, `program.c` has to come *first*, since it doesn't define any symbols the libraries need.

Comment: Thanks @EOF - I'm stupid.

Comment: @SM8: It's a really easy mistake to make, and infuriatingly difficult to spot. Also, it's a bit esoteric *why* the order even matters at all. Don't beat yourself up over it.

Comment: Found an answer that actually explains the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/3185968

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this from the ubuntu forums. The order of the arguments to`gcc` might be the issue

```
gcc -o program program.c `gsl-config --cflags --libs`
```